# Scala Play syntax confustion "&>"

Tags: scala, playframework

I am reading a reactive web programming book about Scala and Play. Can someone explain to me what the following code snippet is about? More specifically, what exactly does `&>` mean? I understand what an iteratee and enumerator is.

```
val jsonStream: Enumerator[JsValue] =
enumerator &>
Encoding.decode() &>
Enumeratee.grouped(JsonIteratees.jsSimpleObject)
```

Comment: I can't explain this very well but have you seen this https://gist.github.com/oscarrenalias/3914875

Comment: Thanks! actually i will still mark it as a correct answer even if you just paste the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain this very well but have you seen this [Cheatsheet Play enumerators, enumeratees, iterators and iteratees](http://gist.github.com/oscarrenalias/3914875)

from document

Enumerator &> -> filters the output of the enumerator through an Enumeratee